# How to insert Appointments table with .json data includes doctorID and patientID?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to build relationship between my appointment,doctor,patient tables.Doctor comes from under department and department also under hospital.Seemed complicated a little for me using .NET EF Code First.

**Model Doctor**

```
public class Doctor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public Department Department { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }

    }
```

**Model Patient**

```
  public class Patient
    {   
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string IdentityNumber { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } 
        public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
    }
```

**Model Appointment**

```
  public class Appointment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public int DoctorId { get; set; }
        public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
        public Patient Patient { get; set; }

    }
```

Basically appointment belongs to doctor and patient(not necessary can be null).If appointment hasn't booked yet by any patient,then patientID null else patient ID will be equal to patient ID who has booked the appointment.For Doctor ID also that will be same.

I want to start application with data so these are appointment json that I've created below

```
[
  {
    "IdentityNumber": "21907141860",
    "Name": "Ali",
    "BirthDate": "2017-02-07T10:04:33 -03:00",
    "Email": "timucininmaili@gmail.com"
  },
  {
    "IdentityNumber": "12906141850",
    "Name": "Veli",
    "BirthDate": "2017-02-07T10:04:33 -03:00",
    "Email": "timucininmaili@gmail.com"

  },
  {
    "IdentityNumber": "22605131860",
    "Name": "Timucin",
    "BirthDate": "2017-02-07T10:04:33 -03:00",
    "Email": "timucininmaili@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

But I don't know how to map these appointments with DoctorID and PatientID on the appointment table.Should I add object array of doctor and patient under appointment or something else I don't know.

**Expected output**
AppointmentID-DoctorID-PatientID(if doesnt exist its null)-Appointment Date

**Actual output**
No appointment comes.All columns are empty(But Doctors and patients tables are created succesfully with their .json)

**Json Example to fill Doctors under Hospital**

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Concetta Hospital",
    "Location": "United States",
    "Departments": [
      {
        "name": "Eye",
        "Doctors": [
          {
            "name": "Sean Paul",
            "title": "Eye Doctor"
          }
        ]
```

**Json Example to fill Patients**

```
  {
    "IdentityNumber": "12906141850",
    "Name": "Veli",
    "BirthDate": "2017-02-07T10:04:33 -03:00",
    "Email": "timucininmaili@gmail.com"
  }
```

**Appointment .Json**

```
   {
        "AppointmentDate": "2017-02-07T10:04:33 -03:00",
        "Status": true
      },
      {
        "AppointmentDate": "2016-02-07T10:04:33 -03:00",
        "Status": true
      },
      {
        "AppointmentDate": "2018-02-07T10:04:33 -03:00",
        "Status": true
      }
```

**Seed.cs(The way how I populate my tables after migration)**

```
 var patientData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Data/PatientSeed.json");
        var patients = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Patient>>(patientData);
        foreach (var patient in patients)
        {
            byte[] passwordhash, passwordSalt;
            CreatePasswordHash("password", out passwordhash, out passwordSalt);
            patient.PasswordHash = passwordhash;
            patient.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;
            patient.Name = patient.Name.ToLower();
            context.Patients.Add(patient);
        }

        var appointmentData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Data/AppointmentSeed.json");
        var appointments = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Appointment>>(appointmentData);
        foreach (var appointment in appointments)
        {
            context.Appointments.Add(appointment);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: What's your appointment json ? The appointment json you provided above seems to be the patient json .

Comment: @XueliChen I forgot to add sorry.I've just added you can see

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map these appointments with DoctorID and PatientID on the appointment table , you should contians the related info of doctor and patient in the appointment.json.Here is a demo :

1. Appointment.Json

   ```
   [
    {
     "AppointmentDate": "2017-02-07T10:04:33 -03:00",
     "Status": true,
     "Type": "Eye",
     "PatientIdentityName": "21907141860",
     "DoctorName": "Sean Paul"
    },
   {
    "AppointmentDate": "2016-02-07T10:04:33 -03:00",
    "Status": true,
    "Type": "Tooth",
    "PatientIdentityName": "12906141850",
    "DoctorName": "Aisha Ni"
   },
   {
    "AppointmentDate": "2018-02-07T10:04:33 -03:00",
    "Status": true,
    "Type": "Eye",
    "PatientIdentityName": "22605131860",
    "DoctorName": "Daniel Li"
   }
   ]
   ```

2.Model Appointment and use a  AppointmentViewModel to get the jsondata

```
public class Appointment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DoctorId")]
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }

    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PatientId")]
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
}

public class AppointmentViewModel
{
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string PatientIdentityName { get; set; }
    public string DoctorName { get; set; }
}
```

3.DataSeeder

```
var appointmentData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Data/AppointmentSeed.json");
            var appointmentVMs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AppointmentViewModel>>(appointmentData);
            foreach (var appointment in appointmentVMs)
            {
                var departmentId = context.Departments.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Name == appointment.Type).Id;
                Appointment model = new Appointment();

                model.AppointmentDate = appointment.AppointmentDate;
                model.Status = appointment.Status;
                model.DoctorId = context.Doctors.SingleOrDefault(d => d.Name == appointment.DoctorName && d.DepartmentId == departmentId).Id;
                model.PatientId = context.Patients.SingleOrDefault(p => p.IdentityNumber == appointment.PatientIdentityName).Id;
                context.Appointments.Add(model);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
```